# Caluculating sum of activity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which is with following kind of information

```
activity     cost    order   date  other information
10            1       100     --
20            2       100
10            1       100
30            4       100
40            4       100
20            2       100
40            4       100
20            2       100
10            1       101
10            1       101
20            1       101
```

My requirement is to get sum of all activities over a work order
ex: for order 100

1+2+4+4=11

1(for activity 10)
2(for activity 20)
4 (for activity 30) etc.

i tried with group by, its taking lot time for calculation. There are 1lakh plus records in warehouse. is there any possibility in efficient way.

```
SELECT SUM(MIN(cost))
FROM COST_WAREHOUSE a
WHERE   order = 100
GROUP BY (order, ACTIVITY)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to get the sum of cost for distinct tuples of (activity, order, cost)

```
SELECT SUM(COST)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT activity, order, cost 
     FROM COST_WAREHOUSE WHERE order = 100) AS A
```

Comment: This addresses the correctness first. When you refer to better performance, what is your benchmark? If you are referring to your query as the benchmark, then I am afraid, I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: i know its really tough job to measure performance with out knowing the underlying structure. In my table Cost for an activity will be same at any instance. Thats how when i group it (then either the min or max) will result a single unique value.

Comment: Oh! there seems to some normalization issue here. anyway, your version would perform better, afaik, over the one I provided that has an inner query that tries to get the DISTINCT records, before applying the aggregate function, but I would say that's marginal and I would still go with mine for the correctness it guarantees, as your table still allows a different cost for an activity as there are no constraints preventing that :)